# Should we have tags for Japanese joinery and/or hand tools?

Tags: discussion, tags

Japanese woodworking has a significant following among hand tool woodworkers. Woodworking.SE already has [several questions](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/search?q=japanese) related to Japanese hand tools and joinery techniques.

Would the site benefit from specific Japanese woodworking tag(s)?

For example, we might find useful [japanese-joinery](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-joinery) or [japanese-hand-tools](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/japanese-hand-tools).

Answer (score 3):

I could definitely see Japanese-joinery as a useful tag.  it is fairly distinct from most of western joinery.  The japanese-hand-tools I might be more willing to wait and see if we get enough volume to warrant it?